# what [sing.] means in a dictionary?

Tags: meaning

i have encountered many **[sing.]** existings in Oxford English dictionary.Fox example  ,

[image]

what that means?I have look up in different dictionaries but i can't find a proper answer or a authorized one.
please help.

Comment: This was just asked in the room. It stands for "singular." That means the word in question, which you left out, represents only one of something, as opposed to "plural," which means two or more. For example, "woman" is singular, and "women" is plural. Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means '**singular**'. Telling you the word you read is in its **singular** **form**.
Whereas **plu.** means **plural** **form**. Some dictionaries will divide the words as (c) or (uc); countable and uncountable similar to singular and plural.

singular: scare; a sudden feeling of fear.

plural: scares; plural of scare.

Comment: A single word? I thought it meant a word referring to only one of something. I think that may be what you meant, but the way you worded it sounds confusing, at least to me.

Comment: You are right. It is confusing. I will word it better in a second. How is it now?

Comment: Cool. I figured that's what you meant. Thanks for the response!

Comment: You are welcome. Sorry for confusion.